# import a csv file into powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

i try to read data into powershell with a csv file, i want to achieve something like that

```
name 
------
peter 
hans
```

but i get something like this:

```
name;alter 
---------- 
peter;klaus
hans;dieter
```

my code looks like this:

```
$CSV= Import-Csv \\D\test.csv

$csvFiles = $CSV 

$csvFiles
```

i know that i have to select in following code that i only want "names" but if i edit my code to:

```
$CSV= Import-Csv \\D\test.csv

$csvFiles = $CSV | Select-Object 'name'

$csvFiles
```

i only get

```
name
----
```

Edit:

[image]

the file is saved csv utf8

csv in notepad++

```
name;alter
peter;klaus
hans;dieter
```

Comment: if your delimiter is not a comma, then you likely need to use the `-Delimiter` parameter to set it to the correct char. your sample seems to use a semicolon.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i also tought that but it dont work that way too

Comment: @du7ri Please expand on "dont work". Does `Import-Csv \\D\test.csv -Delimiter ';'` produce an error? Same output? Different output? Computer catched on fire?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i get the output `name;
-----` i dont know if somehing isnt right with my csv, but i dont think something is wrong with it

Comment: @du7ri - please add to your Question - [A] the 1st 3 lines of your csv file wrapped in code formatting. ///// [B] the result you get when importing that part of that file - again, wrapped in code formatting.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey part b i dont got

Comment: Open your csv with notepad CTRL+A > CTRL+C > Edit your question > CTRL+V > Save.

Comment: @du7ri - please, do not post _images of code/errors/data._ why lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: If your CSV looks like that then Mathias's answer should be working fine

Comment: i tried again @SantiagoSquarzon now it works, thanks all !